# Android fragments and the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I am building an android app that uses a drawer navigation and it looks and works well except i cant add the current view (fragment) to the back stack to get allow the user navigate the app more easily. at the moment the back button just exits the app when pressed. i have looked at various questions on here and none have worked.

Here is my current attempt and dont understand why it dosent work.

```
    if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
//            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new  GalleryFragment()).commit();
//            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);

        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new GalleryFragment());
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

**edit**

**onbackPressed**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    int backCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I sure hope `GalleryFragment()` is not retained using `setRetainInstance(true)`.

Comment: @Lakhan When adding to backstack in the transaction one should not need to override `onBackPressed`

Comment: The code is from your activity, right? Not a fragment?

Comment: @Tapirboy that is correct its in the main activity where the fragments are being loaded into. i have accepted an answer bellow. i did hot handle the back btn being pressed in onBackPressed(). it is now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to control your transaction when back button pressed of android then use below code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

// initialize variables
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

// check to see if stack is empty
if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {          
    fm.popBackStack();
    ft.commit();    
}
else {
    if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Nochmal drücken zum Beenden!", 4000).show();
this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
} else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: ok so your saying it may be working im just not getting the item from the backstack when the back is pressed @vishaljangid

Answer (score 1):

```
instead of doing
super.onBackPressed();
```

Pop the top state off the back stack using the below condition

```
    if(backCount >0){
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one ?

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new GalleryFragment());
ft.addToBackStack("gallery_fragment");
ft.commit();
```

Hope this will help you.